# Single line if null or int return

Tags: c#, if-statement, integer, nullable, dbnull

I'm trying single line if statement as follow and I'm getting error justifiably.How should i do it?

```
int? n;
n = (reader[0] == null)? null : Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
```

Comment: Beware of the difference between null and DBNull

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explicitly cast to `int?` like:

```
n = (reader[0] == null)? null :(int?) Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
```

Or:

```
n = (reader[0] == null) ? (int?) null : Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
```

Comment: BTW you can also cast `null`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, yup. That is true.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need an if statement?

```
n = (int?) reader[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Habib's answer is correct. However, I sometimes find the following convention easier to read:

```
int? n = null;
if (reader[0] != null)
    n = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid trying to do too many things in one line of code.

It's less maintainable, it's less readable and it compiles down to the same MSIL anyway.

Something like this is much more readable:

```
int? number = null;

if (reader[0] != null)
{
    number = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
}
```